# Add a straight line in shinyApp interface

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shinyApp that allows you to display graphs.

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are several interactive displays in the left side.

I would like to create some kind of separation between these interactives and the plot. A discrete straight line would be enough.

Something like the next image.

[image]

Where can I search to find this? Should be some css or js function?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_vertical_line.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your ui is build up with a fluidPage, fluidRow with columns.

You can add in the column the style attribute and add a left border to the column holding your plot.

Some basic shiny example taken from their tutorials and I added a red border there

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                  min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)
    ),
    column(
      8,
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      style = "border-left: 1px solid red;"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]